# Modifying mat-checkbox to include a + symbol in an unchecked state (Angular-Material)

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, angular-material

This is the current HTML for checkbox.html, inside the angular/material2 'mat-checkbox' component.

```
<div class="mat-checkbox-background">
      <svg version="1.1"
           focusable="false"
           class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"
           viewBox="0 0 24 24"
           xml:space="preserve">
        <path class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"
              fill="none"
              stroke="white"
              d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3"/>
      </svg>
      <!-- Element for rendering the indeterminate state checkbox. -->
      <div class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want the following: 
+ disabled: plus sign
+ unchecked: plus sign
+ checked: default checkmark
+ indeterminate: whatever it currently is by default

The way it works now is that in a default (unchecked) state the checkmark is set to opacity 0; is there any way, instead of just having that opacity change, I can have a different SVG value instead?

The challenge I'm working within is that, as it currently stands, I need to use the 'mat-checkbox' component instead of just creating a custom component. That may be an option but it has to extend the mat-checkbox component and use all of it's existing functionality (accessibility, watchers, indeterminate state management, etc). 
I just don't know Angular 5 (2+) well enough to do this without some coaching.